# Synology VPN why 'what's my IP' is not correct

Tags: vpn, synology

I setup Synology VPN server. When connecting from TunnelBlick client, it connect to my home and I am able to access LAN computer.

But, if check 'what's my IP', the IP is not my home IP service provider provided IP.

I am expecting IP is home IP.

What's is wrong with my setting?

Comment: Why do you expect to see your ISP IP Address instead of TunnelBlock considering that is the entire point of using TunnelBlock.  The reason you are still able to access your LAN is due to the configuration of the VPN.

Comment: What address _are_ you seeing?

Comment: I set up another VPN in same LAN, but from router. I saw my home IP in client. Client MacPro connects from Starbucks, after VPN connect from MacPro, browser should see "What's my IP" to be home IP, NOT Starbucks IP. My router VPN is expected, but Synology VPN is NOT expected. Synology VPN does not work in China Firewall, google.com not work. Router VPN work in China Firewall.